# User preprocess not working

Tags: theming, 8, users

I'm trying to pass a variable to an user template, here is my code:

```
function template-name_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['foo'] = 'foo';
}
```

It doesn't work. I tried adding these line in the core User module preprocess and it works!

Comment: What do you mean by _template-name_ in `template-name_preprocess_user()`? Drupal doesn't use a name like that for template hooks. It uses `template_preprocess_user()`, `THEMENAME_preprocess_user()`, or `MODULENAME_preprocess_user()`.

Answer (score 5):

Template hooks like [`template_preprocess_user()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user/8.2.x) are implemented by custom module/theme by replacing `template` with `[MODULE_NAME/THEME_NAME]`. So, for example, if your theme short name is bartik, then the function name will be `bartik_preprocess_user()` which will be implemented in the bartik.theme file.

```
function [MODULE/THEME_NAME]_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['foo'] = 'foo';
}
```

Comment: Yeah, either the hook is misnamed or caches weren't cleared.